# How to loop through processes and kill it if cpu usage is less than x

Tags: bash, awk, grep

So my goal is to kill processes that get stuck transcoding media. All processes are monitored by runit so when the process gets killed - it gets restarted.

I can get the list of processes the following way:

```
ps aux | grep -v grep | grep ffmpeg | awk '{print $2, $3}'
```

What would I need to have any processes killed that returns <20 on $3 - in other words, process is using less then 20% of CPU?

Comment: Do you know about `pgrep` & `pkill` ?

Comment: Read on it but I am not sure how I can use it achieve what I need

Answer (score 1):

[pgreg(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pgrep.1.html) can give you a list of pids. So `pgrep ffmpeg`  will give you a list (like e.g.`2345 15678 9870`) of pids of processes running `ffmpeg`. Hence `ps u $(pgrep ffmpeg)` gives you a process list.

You want to filter those processes running for less than 20% of CPU. Try

```
ps u $(pgrep ffmpeg) | awk '{if ($3 < 20.0) { print "kill " $2 }}'
```

This should give you several lines like `kill 12345`. Feed them to a shell:

```
  ps u $(pgrep ffmpeg) | awk '{if ($3 < 20.0) { print "kill " $2 }}' | sh
```

You probably could use [pkill(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pgrep.1.html) and [GNU awk](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html)  function [system](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#index-system_0028_0029-function). You may want to skip the title line output by `ps u` perhaps by giving also `/USER/{next}` to `awk`

Answer (score 1):

Another approach using using awk without grep

```
ps aux|awk '{if($11~ "ffmpeg" && $3<20.0){system("kill -9 "$2)}}'

($11~ "ffmpeg" && $3<20.0) # if field $11 (COMMAND column) matches "ffmpeg" and field $3 (PID column) is less than 20.0, kill PID no. which is in field $2
```

Comment: I don't think that ̀ `kill -9`  (better spelt as `kill -KILL`) should be done without trying *before* `kill -TERM`

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this:

```
ps axo comm,pid,pcpu | awk '/^ffmpeg/ && $3 < 20 {print $2}' | xargs -r kill -9
```